# Stitcher in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I'm trying to use the Stitcher class in JavaCV.  However I've accessed the maven repos and I cannot find the Stitcher class.  I've also looked at the head of the source and that doesn't seem to have a Stitcher class either.  Am I looking in the wrong place for it; I'm accessing javacv, jaavcpp and the java version for my platform (windows 32 bit).

If anyone could tell me where to get hold of the stitcher class in JavaCV I'd be very grateful!

Regards,

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_stitching.Stitcher but eclipse cannot find it